# extending Android DDMS Plugin, Err: Can´t bind to local 8700 for debugger

Tags: android, ddms

i want to extend the Android DDMS Plugin.
I followed all [steps](http://tools.android.com/build/eclipse) and the further sites.

Every time I start the orginal, unchanged "ddms-plugin" Project as Eclipse Application, i get this warning:
„Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it´s being used by something else, shoose a new port number in the preferences”
AFAIK it´s ok to ignore this warning, because there are two Eclipse instances with a DDMS-Plugin.

But after i start an Android Application, i get the warning:
„Can´t bind to local 8700 for debugger“
What could cause this warning?
Typical solutions like adding localhost in the hosts-file or 10.0.2.2 (or 127.0.0.1) as ADB-Host doesnt help.
The port is also available.

In the first instance of eclipse there is no warning at all in the ddms-plugin.

Any ideas?

Comment: This was actually Avast anti virus for me... Disabled the Home Network Shield and my problems went away